# Cannot assign union member as NULL

Tags: c, pointers, unions

I have a union definition as follows:

```
union simple_list
{
    simple_list *next;
    int *s;
};
```

This is my main function:

```
int main()
{
    simple_list *sl;
    sl->next = NULL; // core dumped, why?

    simple_list sl1;
    sl1.next = NULL; // this will be fine

    simple_list *sl2;
    sl->next = sl2; // this also will be fine

    return 0;
}
```

Can't I access one of union members by pointer?

Additions:
Now, the answer is clear. Because I tried to access a pointer before allocating memory for it, and this kind of operation is undefined.
I modified my codes like this, then everything is okay.

```
simple_list *sl = (simple_list*)malloc(sizeof(union simple_list));
```

However, I find another problem:

```
int main()
{
    simple_list *sl = (simple_list*)malloc(sizeof(union simple_list));
    sl->next = NULL;  // this should be fine and it does

    simple_list *sl1;
    sl1->next = NULL; // amazing! this also be fine, "fine" means no core dumped

    return 0;
}
```

Does this means that an undefined operation may(not must) cause core dumped error?

I compile my C codes with gcc 4.8.4.
Ubuntu 14.04 virtual machine.

### Update:2015-12-16

cored dumped means segmentation fault. I read some books about OS recently, segmentation fault means that you try to access some memory that have not been allocated for you. When I declare a pointer but not allocate memory for it, the pointer is dangling. Dangling means that this pointer is possible to point to anywhere, so it is reasonable deference the point successfully or not successfully. So far so good!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to allocate memory for `sl` before assignment. Otherwise, `sl->next = NULL;` will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Does this answer help OP?

Comment: Aside from all the UB that I point out, and the fact that it's a little imprecise, I dare say it does help. I am one of the upvoters. I've always been fond of a brief answer.

Comment: @Kay; Why not?? Do you think I should write how to allocate memory?

Comment: Your answer is better, now. Maybe you could add a word why you should not dereference a pointer before any value was assigned to it. I.e. the lack of a default value.

Comment: @Kay; There are many thing that can be added to the answer and adding those things is not gonna improve it, like you said: "*you should not dereference a pointer before any value was assigned to it*": Yes true, but not for this answer. No pointer dereference here. Only initialisation. The answer is precise.

Answer (score 3):

A `union` is a tricky beast in C. *Undefined behaviour* is never too far away. In detail:

1. `simple_list *sl; sl->next = NULL;` The behaviour is *undefined*. You haven't assigned the pointer `sl` to any memory.
2. `simple_list sl1; sl1.next = NULL;` That's fine. Just don't attempt to read back the `s` member, as the behaviour on doing so is *undefined*.
3. `simple_list *sl2; sl->next = sl2;` No, this is *undefined behaviour* too, as you're reading an uninitialised pointer value.

The third point is quite subtle. Most folk know that *dereferencing* an uninitialised pointer is undefined, but *reading* one too is also undefined in most instances; this one included.

Comment: The fact that there's a union involved doesn't even matter here. None of this would be any different with a struct.

Answer (score 2):

```
simple_list *sl;
```

Declares pointer to `simple_list`, doesn't allocate memory and pointer doesn't point to valid `union`.

```
sl->next = NULL; // core dumped, why?
```

because see above. This union instance doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Allocate memory to your pointer `s1`.

```
s1 = malloc(sizeof(union simple_list));
```

Also this code will not compile.

You need to have your union type for a variable inside the union.

```
union simple_list
{
    union simple_list *next;
    int *s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate the object!

```
simple_list* s1 = malloc(sizeof(simple_list));
s1->next = NULL;
```

Comment: Use `malloc`, not `new`; see the language tag: [C].

Comment: Allocation fixed. Thanks.